# Which Operations unlock uniforms for my character in COD Ghosts?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

I'd like a list of operations for each of the uniform pieces in COD Ghosts but I can't seem to find one.  Does one exist?

Answer (score 1):

All I can tell you is go to your Gear opperations and check there. Also I can tell you that for the Gillie Suite you must get 800 kills using Chrome Lined on your snipers. Remember that you must have the opperation in your list of opperations to be able to complete this.